# Rewrite index.php to root with variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, get

I am setting up my htaccess and everything is working the way I want it to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

#rewrite pages
RewriteRule ^photo/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /photo.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /video.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^quote/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /quote.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /post.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^author/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /author.php?display_name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /tag.php?tag_name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /category.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ /blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^videos/$ /videos.php [L]
RewriteRule ^photos/$ /photos.php [L]
RewriteRule ^coming-soon/$ /coming-soon.php [L]
RewriteRule ^404/$ /404.php [L]

#add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]

#error redirect
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

How would I go about setting it up so that `index.php?page=2` redirects to `mydomain.com/2/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#error redirect
ErrorDocument 404 /404

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

#add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]

#rewrite pages
RewriteRule ^photo/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /photo.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /video.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^quote/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /quote.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /post.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^author/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /author.php?display_name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /tag.php?tag_name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /category.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ /blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^videos/$ /videos.php [L]
RewriteRule ^photos/$ /photos.php [L]
RewriteRule ^coming-soon/$ /coming-soon.php [L]
RewriteRule ^404/$ /404.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Always keep redirect rules before internal rules and keep catch-all type rules at the bottom.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you for the instruction. I just started learning htaccess so that is a big help.